# Salesforce - Reverse lookup geo into an address

Tags: type-conversion, salesforce, geo

I am struggling with this, at the moment we have an application that sends the Lat and Long to Salesforce which we store in two seperate geo code fields.

For example
Subscriber_lat = *latitude*
Subscriber_long = *longitude*
We need this converted to
Address = 14 Street Name Street, Suburb, State, Country, Postcode

The problem we have is we want to convert this to an address so we can report on it (e.g. Suburbs, States etc)

Does anyone know of a solution here?

Michael

Comment: You'll need to subscribe for a service to convert that lat/long to a rough address. Google's Map's API might be of use

Answer (score -1):

A service such as [Google Map's API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) can do this.

> Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup) The term geocoding generally refers
>   to translating a human-readable address into a location on a map. The
>   process of doing the opposite, translating a location on the map into
>   a human-readable address, is known as reverse geocoding.
>
> Required parameters in a reverse Geocoding request:
>
> latlng — The latitude and longitude values specifying the location for
>   which you wish to obtain the closest, human-readable address.
>
> key — Your application's API key. This key identifies your application
>   for purposes of quota management.

Comment: How would you impliment this into salesforce though?

Comment: there's a handful of ways, you can have a trigger do a @future callout to the service and populate the records for instance, or you can have it run on a scheduled basis once a day. it depends on the data volume and how instantaneous you want it populated. I would suggest you look through the documentation and make an attempt of coming up with a solution and creating a new question with any problems you come across.